# What is the best site to find verb/noun collocation pairs?

Tags: resource

When writing German I often write a noun and then wonder which verb would be the best first for it, e.g. I write

> bei einer Firma, wo wir eine ähnliche Lösung ***_*__*_*___** haben.

then I wonder what would be the best verb:

- eingesetzt
- gefunden
- gebaut

It would be nice to have a (concordance?) site to go to where I type in "Lösung" and it tells me the ten most common verbs used with that noun.

Where is the best site to get this kind of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+"lösung * haben" ingenieur | projekt
```

I use linguee quite alot (probably uses a own search algorithm for google and mainly the google index, someone knows?), but why not use google itself? Linguee seems to fit better if you want correct translation of a phrase, searching google with code above you also find

> Lösung **entwickelt/erarbeitet** haben (which sounds imo much better than *gefunden/gebaut*)

I added `ingenieur | projekt` for the correct context/people using this formulation

Answer (score 2):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/) has some limited capabilities to find computer generated associations with adjectives, [verbs](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Loesung#verben) or other nouns. However some of these results don't make sense or are immensely dependent on context (e.g. here *"einen"*.

Another place you can look up is [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=L%C3%B6sung) where some citations are listed for a given word.

Answer (score 2):

Linguee works reasonably well, but doesn't give statistics:

http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/eine+%E4hnliche+l%F6sung.html

Answer (score 0):

But the most often used term needn't be a good choice. For example, if you construct something, `gebaut` can be appropriate, but maybe `gefunden`, which would fit for creative work, research and so on better, is in general used more often, but your `building` solution might not involve research at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I consider your sentence snippet as insufficient to recognize the context, and I'm sceptical, that any dictionary will by chance find an appropriate combination.

It is important, whether you just configured an off-the-shelf solution (then *konfiguriert* or simply *im Einsatz* would fit), whether you intelligently combined some of such solutions or really implemented something from scratch (in both cases *entwickelt* or *implementiert* would fit).

*Gefunden* may sound too occasional for any systematic commercial approach, and *gebaut* reminds me on developer's slang.

Answer (score -4):

You can find the collocations you are looking for at the Sketch Engine's free version:

https://skell.sketchengine.eu/#home