# Verb/noun pairs in German (collocation)

Tags: verb, noun

I am a native English speaker, relatively fluent in German - but something I continue to find quite difficult is to get a sense of which verb is appropriate for a given noun.  It's possible this is idiomatic, but there are definitely combinations which are seldom, if ever used by native speakers.

A very simple example:

> - I would *drive* a car
> - I would *create* an opportunity
> - I would *take* a picture
> - I would *determine* a solution

Obviously I could *pilot* a car, for example - it is technically fine, but it doesn't sound native at all.

Likewise, a native German would never say "Ich nehme ein Foto", unless they're actually taking something, I suppose.

What I'm wondering about here is linguistic tendency - for example, I've read that the (American) English tendency is to put shortest words first in a list of words e.g. "I saw a dog, a cat, and a walrus."  It's just something that's done, but knowing this would help someone learning English tremendously, I believe.

**Is there a similar linguistic tendency with noun/verb pairings that could be used a generalized rule?**

I did find a similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-is-the-best-site-to-find-verb-noun-collocation-pairs9783596180981), and provided great references, but wondering about the tendency.

Comment: There's also a tendency in German to sort a list of words by length, or to rearrange words for rhythmic reasons, but that doesn't help with noun/verb pairs. I've never figured out any rule for English noun/verb pairs (do you know any?); I just had to learn the expression (or assimilate it when I read it somewhere). I suppose it's the same with German.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine this is just as hard in English - the only one I concretely know is "make" and "do" (probably 80% of the second-language speakers mix the two up) - it boils down to definition - "make" is "to construct", in this sense, where as "do" is "to act". [This](http://esl.about.com/od/engilshvocabulary/a/collocations.htm) might help to some extent.

Comment: What about something like "make way" and "make do", then? I don't think there's an easy alternative to simply learning collocations.

Comment: That's a good point Ingmar - I would argue that "make way" means "to construct a way", so that follows.  Can't explain make do, other than to agree - it's idiomatic for sure.  I figured as much, but I was curious if there was any sort of linguistic observation beyond that.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but Ingmar piqued my interest: [make do](http://grammarist.com/usage/make-do-make-due/)

Comment: I must be missing your point here, because I really don't understand the question. What kind of rule are you thinking of? One which explains why you don't determine a car or drive a solution? And how is this related to the "dog, cat, walrus" example?

Comment: The "dog, cat, walrus" example was just put there as an example of a linguistic tendency.  I was simply wondering if there is such a tendency one could cite related to collocation of verbs/nouns in German.  I was looking for something like "There is a tendency to always use NounX with VerbY".  There may not be something like this, but that's what I was wondering.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: To partially answer the question: Yes, of course, there's a tendency. There's a good reason why collocation dictionaries exist. However, you cannot put this in a 'rule' similar to the order of adjectives. – If you'd like to know which verb/nouns often go together, I'm afraid but there's no good German corpus providing this feature. Wortschatz-Portal gives you the most significant collocations, but I'm truly missing an equivalent to BNC(British English) or COCA(American English).

Comment: This feels like the sort of thing best learned by repeated communication in German - reading and hearing the regularly used phrases and verb pairings.  You can get better answers with questions on specific pairings, but I think most languages just require a lot of experience with their contours and peculiarities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a similar linguistic tendency with noun/verb pairings. Idiomatic use of such pairings must be learned like formulas. Otherwise it violates the feel for language of native speakers.

They just have a history where it comes from, and why it's different from other languages.

Usually, alternative forms slightly change the focus or meaning of what you want to express, or change the level of language, or serve regional variations; like in your *pilot a car* example.

Sometimes such pairing may develop due influence of foreign languages or cultural progress (like `hat Sinn` vs. `macht Sinn`).

Comment: Actually 'macht Sinn' is probably one of the worst examples, because semantically speaking an object cannot do (machen) anything. However, it is used very commonly and therefore understood, while the proper use would be 'ergibt Sinn'.

Comment: @Martin: the change of meaning is probably that *machen* became a synonym of *ergeben*, like in *Das macht eins fuffzich!*.

Comment: I wouldn't call "Sinn machen" instead of "Sinn ergeben" exactly cultural *progress* (which AFAIU would imply that "Sinn machen" were somehow better than "Sinn ergeben"). Cultural *change* would be a better term here, I think.

Comment: @celtschk: you can assign it to *influence of foreign languages* (as direct adaptation of *make sense*)